# How do I determine the PID of the shell running a given pts/tty?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, tty, proc

There are many ways to obtain the PTS associated with a given process - such as using the `tty` command or resolving `/proc/self/fd/0` (assuming it's open and not redirected) - but what about the inverse? How do I obtain the PID of the shell running the pts?

I can try to use something like `ps -t $(tty)` but this does not provide enough information to reliably determine the root shell (i.e. multiple shell instances, PID reuse on long running systems, etc). The only way I can think of to this is to manually collect all processes associated with the terminal and visit each process's `/proc` entry to determine process hierarchy and then assume it's the topmost parent process.

Is there a simple inverse `tty` command I can use? One that gives me the PID without too much work?

Comment: "visit each process's /proc entry to determine process hierarchy" ... Does `ps -t $(tty) --forest` help with that?

Comment: I assume it could if `ps` guarantees that the topmost process returned is also the root of the forest, but I'm unsure if there aren't any edge cases I should account for. If there's a proper way to query linux's tty subsystem, or have a link to it, it would be much more preferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `ps` command supports sorting by the start time, you can find the earliest process that has this tty.

```
$ ps --sort start_time -t pts/138 |head -2
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
13326 pts/138  00:00:02 bash
```

If your `ps` doesn't support that, you can still get the pid of the earliest process with the tty by sorting all the relevant pids by their start time (the 22nd field in `/proc/<pid>/stat` - *"The time the process started after system boot"*) and getting the pid with the lowest one:

```
$ for p in $(ps -o pid -t pts/138 |tail -n +2); do awk -v PID=$p '{print $22,PID}' /proc/$p/stat 2>/dev/null; done | sort -g | head -1 | awk '{print $2}'
13326
```

Or in a more readable way:

```
$ for p in $(ps -o pid -t pts/138 |tail -n +2)
do
  awk -v PID=$p '{print $22,PID}' /proc/$p/stat 2>/dev/null
done | sort -g | head -1 | awk '{print $2}'
13326
```